# Forbidden non-null assertion lint error for document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lint

I am using TypeScript, and I have the following definition:

```
const contentElement = document.getElementById("contentId")!;
```

Where I know for sure the relevant element is defined in the HTML file with `contendId`.

I have ran eslint, and I get the following error:

```
Forbidden non-null assertion.
```

So... What would be the proper way to handle this case? Tending to simply add a suppress warning, as the other options would simply just increase complexity. But maybe I am overlooking a simple solution here, other than adding:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
```

Comment: Why is there a `!` there?

Comment: @epascarello That's the non-null assertion.

Comment: `const contentElement = document.getElementById("contentId") as HTMLInputElement`

Comment: @epascarello I wish that type assertion would be caught by the *no-non-null-assertion* warning as well… It's really the same, but more under-handed.

Comment: You can't be sure that the element exists. browser addons and other services could remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Forbidden non-null assertion.` is just a lint warning/error because your value can be nullable. If you are sure of the value then you can cast it to the expected type like below

```
const contentElement = document.getElementById("contentId") as HTMLElement
```

Comment: Why `HTMLFormElement`?

Comment: just a sample of what element type he is expecting

Comment: Then please make clear it's just a sample by elaborating in your answer

Comment: Hm, this did the trick. Seems I need to re-check the docs of the warning here. Thank you!

Comment: i added an explanation so you can check it